# NSURLConnection compatibility with base64

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, base64, nsurlconnection

I am trying to send certain parameters in the request body while making a `NSURLConnection`.

One of the parameter is `base64` encoded.

this is the parameter -

"GZ3m8ImhowVFr01Jf0UAwUWgJ3MvNYgDmkb0x2cOauw/rwLsPanFIHb6xigvi2WR/z47OOOk8Ur+
ev8U2DI5ThDyNZtjfYyMRql7l6DJ9qlNlftwe7bX6qIzkstUBTI5xor9CBYh19lAkc5I207eZAwZ
arR85hynWJ9IVM/dQ5TNyjLJy5lABBATkWhdGfwi+0VxYyY7iMYjq+Iq1jkizPN1bKgLCJ0duvPz
z003PNQI5oJHuX3zUn3dYl7czUVOwMhJE4SJ7f3U7YuPWJIKfEPaN69h8FsGQRL/+kTx/SdedeiG
/Q4I49duSV9apDrWKX+LGaJsr9nCQ9L+ZGbRFg=="

I don't think its very huge. Or is it?

My request fails every time.
It says "Client closed connection before receiving entire response". 
"500 Internal Server Error"

Is the `base64` paramater causing the problem.

The method type is '`GET`', does `NSURLConnection` allows `base64` encoded objects to be sent with the body?

Comment: Is the server rejecting the request because you should be using POST? Be specific about "My request fails every time".

Comment: Even I was wondering it should be 'POST' and not 'GET'. But I am not sure. Have edited my question regarding failure.

Comment: No, it's not huge. You should be ok with GET. Take a look to your server response; It looks like your client ( I believe it's your iPhone app ) closes the connection too early. Try posting the way you send the request, I believe there must be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base64 has nothing in common to your connection issues. Not to GET nor POST. Base64 is a huge string ( I guess ASCII, but not sure ), and it is transmitted through get or post like a regular string. Your problem COULD be as follows: you use GET, and try to send an extra-huge Base64 string, which cannot be sent via GET, due to its huge size (as I remember, GET should be used also for non-huge string requests).

Your option: use POST. So you will be able so send huge amount of data as parameter values.